List of valid casts with Rcpp objects
Does anyone know if there is a list of valid casts between Rcpp objects (e.g. IntegerVector) and common C or C++ equivalents?
The reason is that I have a lot of C Code that I would like to be able to integrate with Rcpp, but I really don't want to have to put a lot of loops in converting vectors to Rcpp objects.  If there is an easier solution for this, then I'd also be keen to hear it, though the issue of a list of valid casts is something I have wondered about before.

While you ask for casts (which the compiler/language offer, i.e. the cherished up-cast from int to double etc) I suspect you ask for conversion helpers which Rcpp calls as<>() and wrap().
As is fairly well known, R itself uses only integer (or int or int64_t in C++) and double aka numeric which is also double in C++.  Those work directly (see below), for others it is a little murker because R's logical is actually three-values (TRUE or FALSE or NA !!) so it uses an integer under the hood.
> Rcpp::cppFunction("int mysum(std::vector<int> sv) { \  # really one line
         IntegerVector iv = as<IntegerVector>(wrap(sv)); return(sum(iv)); }")
> mysum(c(3L, 39L))
[1] 42
>

It works the other way around too:
> Rcpp::cppFunction("std::vector<double> minusone(NumericVector nv) \ # one line
        { NumericVector v = nv - 1; return(as<std::vector<double>>(v));}") 
> minusone(c(10.5, 27.28)) 
[1]  9.50 26.28
> 

These are easiest to use if you just keep the type. For std::vector<> or std::list we don't get the nice add-ons as sum here but they work to transfer in and out:
> Rcpp::cppFunction("std::vector<int> setzero(std::vector<int> iv) { \
       iv[1] = 0; return(iv); }")
> setzero(10:12)
[1] 10  0 12
> 

I am not sure a 'list' of all converters exist. Some are tucked away in headers in the package, some are in add-on packages.
